# Models permission in Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I need to give 766 permission to common/models in order to generate files using gii module. But when I do that 'Class 'common\models\User' not found' error is thrown. It only works for 755 permisson. What is the problem?

Comment: Yii2 project and all its folder should have 755 permission except `runtime/logs/` and `web` folder which should have 777 permission.
Maybe you haven't set correct ownership.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

766 permission does work only when the file owner is the **web server** `(apache)`.
So 766 wont work if the **web server** is not the owner of the directory.

**766 means:**

```
Owner can: Read/Write/Execute.
Group can: Read/Write.
Public can: Read/Write.
```

**755 means:**

```
Owner can: Read/Write/Execute.
Group can: Read/Execute.
Public can: Read/Execute.
```